# IR signal strengh measurement

Tags: signal, measurement, infrared, transmission-line, field-strength

I have an application where I have multiple IR transmitters/receivers set up to read data.  These are removable and can be set up in a lab environment where I can control distance, light, etc.  I've been searching for a circuit that will let me measure signal strength of an IR transmission, whether it be through a Microcontroller such as an Arduino or through a scope.  However, all I see are people wanting to measure distance using IR.

My goal is to be able to take a brand new device(s) and get a signal strength baseline.  Then I want to compare older devices to that baseline to see if signal strength degrades over time.  Could anyone point me in a general direction?

Comment: If you want to measure device aging, you probably need "real" measuring gear that is periodically calibrated against something you can have lasting faith in - otherwise you may be measuring the aging of your measuring rig.

Comment: What are you trying to measure the degradation of?  The Tx or RX device. In other words do you need a calibrated sender to measure RX sensitivity.....or a calibrated RX to measure sender IR output?

Comment: I want to measure the Rx device.  This device has both Tx and Rx, however, what I'm really interested in understanding is the Rx circuitry.

Answer (score -1):

just connect a photodiode in parallel with a ferrite bead to the scope probe. it won't be particularly sensitive but it will give you something to compare against.

Comment: Would I look for differences in the amplitude of the PWM waveform?  That's where I was headed.  The ferrite bead would be a nice addition and I hadn't thought of that yet.

Comment: yeah, look at the amplitude, the ferrite bead should eat most of the hash produced by your room lights, which is otherwise likely to dominate the signal.

Comment: Thank you.  I was intending on controlling my ambient light when I make my final fixture by enclosing it but I'm going to use the ferrite bead anyway.